# Grunt Task in Release Manager: Default not found

Tags: gruntjs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I cannot get a simple Grunt task to work in release manager. I keep getting Warning: Task "default" not found. Used --force, continuing.  I added --force to keep the build from failing but the grunt task is not processing.  I have logged into the build agent and run grunt manually with no problems.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    'use strict';

```
grunt.initConfig({

    //Read the package.json (optional)
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    // Cache bust css, update AppInsights key, remove all custom js imports from index.html, https url rewrites
    processhtml: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                data: {
                    appInsightsKey: 'f8d00249-dd60-44be-9145-dcb303e5fd19',
                    timestamp: Date.now()
                }
            },
            files:
            {
                'wwwroot/index2.html': ['wwwroot/index.html']
            }
        },
    },
    // Combine and minify all js in /app folder and subfolders into app.min.js
    uglify: {
        dev: {
            src: ['wwwroot/app/app.module.js', 'wwwroot/app/**/*.module.js', 'wwwroot/app/core/*.js', 'wwwroot/app/services/*.js', 'wwwroot/app/layout/*.js', 'wwwroot/app/**/*.js'],
            dest: 'wwwroot/app/app1.min.js'
        }
    },
    // Delete all js except for app.min.js in /app folder and subfolders
    clean: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                force: true
            },
            expand: true,
            src: ['app/**/*.js', '!app/app.min.js']
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-processhtml');
grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-uglify");
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.registerTask("default", "watch");

// If no target provided, default to dev
var target = grunt.option('target') || 'dev';
//grunt.registerTask('default', ['processhtml:' + target, 'uglify:' + target, 'clean:' + target]);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['processhtml:' + target, 'uglify:' + target]);
```

};

[Grunt Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIzXP.jpg)

Comment: Can you add the log from the agent? That might help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot, you specified the **package.json** as grunt file, by default, the file is the js file (e.g. Gruntfile.js), so check whether you specified the correct file.